# How to trade NFTs on Opensea market with smart contract solidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain, opensea

I want to create a smart contract solidity who buy NFT on Opensea.
I can't find explain documentation or exemple, except in javascript with OpenSea SDK. I wrote a code who buy nft with OpenSeaSdk: https://github.com/jecombe/Nfts_trade/blob/main/opensea/javascript/Opensea.js but i want translate this in Solidity. Anybody can help me to start ?

Comment: NFTs are specified under ERC 721, there are lots of docs about them on the net

Comment: Yes i know, but i want interact with Opensea smart contract to buy and sell. on opensea don't explain how can i interact with

Comment: I am not familiar with opensea interface but the way all of them do it is to post contracts on github and then you can derive the ABI and do whatever you want, you will have maximum power to modify or read anything. Here is their repo: https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea , I don't know which is the contract that does buy/sell, you have to search yourself

Comment: Thank's, smart contract who trade is Seaport1.1. (0x00000000006c3852cbEf3e08E8dF289169EdE581) I need to use this methods to buy something but i don't know which one to use and what parameters to give

Comment: well that contract has a lot of pending transactions with `fulfillAdvancedOrder`/`fullfillBasicOrder` input signature, so this is the place to start learning the bunch of contracts they have

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to directly interact with the OpenSea smart contract? If so you can just use Etherscan + Metamask - https://etherscan.io/address/0x00000000006c3852cbEf3e08E8dF289169EdE581#writeContract - is the OpenSea contract.

I'm not sure why you would want to interact directly with the contract when OpenSea has https://opensea.io has a UI for you to use.

Comment: yes i want to to directly interact with Seaport smart contract of opensea. I found documentation about seaport: https://docs.opensea.io/v2.0/reference/seaport-overview